# Photoshop color weirdness after calibrating LCD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profile, proofing, calibration

I've just purchased a calibrator (Eye One Display 2) to calibrate my two screens, because the difference of colours between them was huge. Now that I've calibrated them, the colours are almost identical.

However, now I have a problem with Photoshop that I didn't have before (or at least I didn't have realized). I usually design things for the web, not for printing, so I have it set to use sRGB color profile. Anytime I wanted to export, for instance, a button for a website, I used save for web, as PNG, and there was no difference between what I saw on the browser and what I saw on Photoshop.

Now, it's all different. If I open the image on Chrome and Firefox, the image looks the same on both browsers, but differently from what I see on Photoshop. However, if I activate the "proof colors" option in Photoshop, then the colors match the ones from Chrome and Firefox.

This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Example image]

Obviously a solution would be to always activate Proof Colors, but I'm sure there must be another option. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Setting your color space to proof colors sets photoshop to match the right colorspace instead of the monitor-calibrated colorspace. Exporting for that colorspace will force it to display properly.

Another option would be to set your monitors to sRGB, but that probably wouldn't be a good idea since they don't match.